# How can I parse more than 1 RSS in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, rss

I'm building a News app for a side project, I want to parse a list of RSS to my application(about 10url or more). I already watched all the tutorials that exist in youtube or google, but all of them teach me to fetch only 1 URL. Anyone here suggests me how to do it in Swift?.

For example: 
I have an array contains a list of URL:

```
let feed_tech = [ 
 "https://www.reddit.com/r/Technologies+elm+haskell+emacs+javascript+programming+rust.rss",
 "http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/",
 "https://news.ycombinator.com/rss",
 "http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/index",
 "https://www.theverge.com/rss/index.xml",
 ...
]
```

and I want parse it to my application.

Thank you

Comment: What are you mean 1 RSS ?! Could you please share these RSSs?

Comment: Sorry, I mean URL. example: I have an array contains a list of URL 
let feed_tech = ["https://news.ycombinator.com/rss", "https://www.reddit.com/r/Technologies+elm+haskell+emacs+javascript+programming+rust.rss"]

Comment: Same logic applies. You can't call all the URLs in one request. You have to iterate through the array and call each one individually. Look into Operations and OperationQueue as well if you want to queue the requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

You have to make `DispatchGroup` and iterate over urls to fetch and save data.

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    // Finish all requests
    // Hide Loading
}

// Show Loading

for url in urls {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Update Loading if you'd like
        // For exam: Loading (1 from 10) urls
    }
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    callAndFetchAPI(url, completion: {
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    dispatchGroup.wait()
}
```

If you like to fetch faster you can load two urls on iteration.

This is a good article about DispatchGroup:
[DispatchGroup](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5371-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-2-2)

Comment: Thank you. But when I do that, my app is load so long, I run on XS Max and it takes up to 5s to completely load and show to tableView

Comment: @KhoaLe, You have to show a loading. Seems like these 5 seconds is network load time. Loading data on network takes time.

Comment: ya, let me try.